# How to create a copy of ResultRow without reference?

Tags: views

I need to have different values in each row based on the same row, so I create $this_row from $row. But field_x contains the same value in rendered view. I guess the $row reference is the same and I tried clone $row without success and also deep_copy but it exceeded memory.

What else can I try?

```
# in ..._views_pre_render

$new_rows = array();
foreach ($view->result as $row) {
   foreach ($xs as $x) {
      $this_row = $row;
      $this_field = $this_row->_entity->get('field_x');
      $this_field->setValue($x);
      $new_rows[] = $this_row;   
   }
}
$view->result = $new_rows;
```

Comment: That’s how php works - you’ve assigned a reference to, not a copy of, the original variable to `$new_row`. You might be able to `clone` it, otherwise just pull the scalar values out and use them instead

Comment: clone keeps the reference and deep_copy does not work even with increased memory